# Как правильно открывать фрагменты в MVVM в Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm

Использую в своем проекте MVVM, возник вопрос, как правильно открывать фрагменты в MVVM? Дело в том, что фрагмент и активити у меня используют общую ViewModel для работы. Соответсвенно когда я снова после закрытия вызываю фрагмент, у него сохраняется предыдущее состяние переменных и LiveData, MutableLiveData переменых. А мне нужно новое, пустое состояние для заполнения пользователем данных.

С Navigation Architecture Component еще не знаком, хотелось бы понять как решать такие ситуации без него.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите каждый раз получать новые данные, тут есть несколько решений:

- Используйте разные ViewModels. Уничтожился фрагмент, умерла ViewModel.
- Очищайте ViewModel после того как завершаете работу с фрагментами.
- Можете в вашей ViewModel иметь какие-то стейты и при запуске фрагмента выбирать нужный вам стейт и в зависимости от него грузить нужные данные.
- Стоит так же подумать о том на какие данные и когда вы подписываетесь. Немного странно что у вас создается новый фрагмент и подписывается на данные которые вам не нужны.

Я не до конца уверен, что вам вообще необходимо иметь одну ViewModel для сущностей в которых должны быть разные данные. Поэтому я больше склоняюсь к первому варианту. Но тут надо более полно видеть задачу.

По поводу Navigation Architecture Component. Этот фреймворк мало имеет отношения к вашей задаче. Ну т.е. это просто обертка для более удобной навигации между фрагментами, но как их заполнять он не решает.

Comment: А вот такой вопрос, если я сделаю две разные ViewModel, для фрагмента свою. Подпишу ее ViewmodelProviders на жизненый цикл фрагмента, (this), ведь когда пользователь перевернет экран, он не увидит те данные, что начинал вводить? Не убьет ли активити фрагмент и не создаст его заново, вызвав onCleared у ViewModel фрагмента?

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но скорее всего это должно работать так же как и с активити. Т.е. данные должны сохраниться.